# toogle effect when a check box is clicked

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var cb = $('.customstyle').attr('checked');

    if (cb == "checked"){
        $('.cbox').show();
    }else{
        $('.cbox').hide();
    }

    $(".customstyle").click(function(){
    $('.cbox').toggle('fast');
    });

});
```

from the codes above, firstly it gets the attribute "checked" of ".customstyle" checkbox and then if the variable cb is equal to "checked" then the ".cbox" will be shown else if not then it will be hidden and if the ".customstyle" checkbox is clicked then the ".cbox" is toggled.

the above codes should work as what im trying to do but it is not and also i tried to alert the cb and i get "undefined", whats wrong in this?. Anyone here could tell what supposed the problem, mistake or missing?

Im open in any suggestions, recommendations and idea's. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle with your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".customstyle").change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.cbox').show('fast');
    } else {
        $('.cbox').hide('fast');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jPb7P/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use just:

```
   $(".customstyle").click(function(){
       $('.cbox').toggle(this.checked);
   });
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e97ZW/)

To check the input is `checked` you need to use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and you need to compare it with `== true`, or use `.is(':checked')`